# Magento 2 - How to hidden field of customer edit page

Tags: magento2, customer, customer-account

How to hidden field of customer edit page  in magento 2

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You add one more item tag:

```
<item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
```

to your component which you want to hide.

**Do step by step:**
create one file below:

```
yourPool/yourModule/view/base/ui_component/customer_form.xml
```

Add:

```
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="customer">
        <field name="sendemail_store_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Store\Model\System\Store</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Send Welcome Email From</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">number</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. but i want to hidden this field